# Javascript object representation format

Tags: javascript, object, compiler-construction, intermediate-language

In compiler IR representation, we know that function type can be represented using Cartesian Product.

For example:

```
function my_func(a, b) { return c; }
```

the function type can be denoted as: **(int × double)->int**

(note that here I assume that all types are known)

So, if I declare an object in Javascript like

```
var obj = {"name":"haha", "id":123};
```

Is there any formal representation to represent **obj** which is **object type** in Javascript ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's an `[object Object]`. JavaScript is a unityped language.

Comment: @AmitJoki: Does it matter?

Comment: @cookiemonster, of course it does, as this *is* a good question and that comment is the answer, I suppose

Comment: @AmitJoki: Nah, as long as the OP gets the info, it doesn't really make a difference where the info comes from.

Comment: @cookiemonster, that is where you're going wrong. It's not just about OP but about future readers who might have the same question, but they won't find an answer

Comment: @AmitJoki: Future readers can read comments too, no? If you want to post an answer, you should go ahead.

Comment: @cookiemonster, I've been answering a lot, where elclanrs comments the same as my answer whilst I type. So, I don't want to be framed as the one who copies other's answer :)

Comment: @AmitJoki: I understand, but you shouldn't let that stop you. If someone decides to post an answer as a comment, they have nothing to complain about when someone else posts a similar answer.

Comment: There has to be a duplicate somewhere, but I'm lazy, I don't want to elaborate, feel free to post a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you all. But may I ask that according to my example : 
var obj = {"name":"haha", "id":123};
How to represent this ?
(I mean including all property types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is unityped language. That is, there is no separate `int`, `string`, `double`, `byte` data types. All it has is `var`.

All objects, take the literal form of `[object Object]` when they are converted to strings.

There is no javascript debuggers AFAIK that debugs to such a depth to know all these things.